# How can I add jar file dependencies in gradle

Tags: build, gradle

I try to make jar library by using set of jar files. I copied jar files in lib directory, and here's my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
   fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
}
```

But there's nothing in folder `build/libs/itk-java.jar`

Anyone tell me what I missed in process?

Comment: Why do you think the problem is related to dependencies? It's likely something different, e.g. source files not being in the right location. Without detailed information about your project setup, it's impossible to say more. One thing you can try is to run with `--info` or `--debug` to get more information on what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot see *.jar files in external dependancies (Eclipse or idea)

You can move your *.jar files outside your project directory,

and Set your dependencies corrctly, then you can see your *.jar files in external dependancies